# How to minimize program to system tray in Win32 using Avalonia

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, avaloniaui

I need to be able to minimize the Avalonia window to system tray on Windows. The program runs on multiple platforms but I would like to add this windows specific behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can use P/Invoke + Shell_NotifyIcon. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4768/Basic-use-of-Shell-NotifyIcon-in-Win32 explains how to do it in C++, C# is no different.